# How to make Bootstrap carousel scalable/zoomable by mobile touch where keeping default slide behavior?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4.x carousel. My page is user scalable with `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2, shrink-to-fit=no">`.

The page can be scalable/zoomable by mobile touch (two fingers) when any of the two touch points outside the carousel.

How can I make the scalable work when touch points inside the carousel (where keeping default slide behavior)?

### Edit

I tried to add the following css:

```css
.carousel.pointer-event {
  touch-action: auto;
}
```

Scalable works now, but touching slides left and right stops working.

How can I make both scalable and slides work at the same time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution. Simply add the following css to override the default setup:

```css
.carousel.pointer-event {
  touch-action: pan-y pinch-zoom;
}
```

Comment: i tried it and it works only when we have this: `<meta name="viewport" content="... ,user-scalable=1, ...>`
So, do you think its possible to have zoom only on the carousel item and not the whole document? i mean if we set `user-scalable=0` and still have the zoom feature on carousel with CSS, or limit the user scalable area to that carousel